# Vert.x Hazelcast in Multidocker AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, hazelcast, vert.x

i try to run multiple Vert.x Instances on a EC2 Node via multiple Docker Containers.

Container A:
  Port Forwardning: 5071 -> 5071
  Local IP: 172.17.0.4

Container B:
  Port Forwardning: 5072 -> 5072
  Local IP: 172.17.0.5

Container C:
  Port Forwardning: 5073 -> 5073
  Local IP: 172.17.0.6

i use the Hazelcast Amazon EC2 Setup but this is not working, because the node himself has just one Public IP (set in the Hazelcastsetup) and no possibility to add ports.

How can i run multiple vertx via hazelcast in aws on different ports (maybe this different port solution is not the best one).

Thanks
Marcel

P.s.: i tried to add the nodes via tcp-ip setup, but it's not allowed to mixed AWS and tcp join.

P.p.s: i cannot and don't want use the "--net=host" in AWS ElasticBeanstalk

It looks like this one: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/4537

Update:

my HC Config

```
    JsonObject amazonConfig = clusterConfig.getJsonObject("aws");

    String publicIp = null;
    String privateIp = null;
    String localIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();

    logger.info("Found local IP: " + localIp);

    try {
        publicIp = doHttpUrlConnectionAction("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4");

        logger.info("Found public IP: " + publicIp);

        privateIp = doHttpUrlConnectionAction("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4");
        logger.info("Found private IP: " + privateIp);

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        logger.fatal("Cannot detect public cloud ip");
        throw e;
    }

    logger.info("AWS Cluster config loaded");

    hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().setPublicAddress(privateIp);
    hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().setPortAutoIncrement(false);

    if (amazonConfig.containsKey("hazelcastPort")) {
        logger.info("Use port " + amazonConfig.getString("hazelcastPort") + " for hazelcast");

        hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig()
                .setPublicAddress(privateIp + ":" + amazonConfig.getString("hazelcastPort"));

        hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().setPort(Integer.valueOf(amazonConfig.getString("hazelcastPort")));
    }

    // hazelcastConfig.setProperty("hazelcast.local.localAddress",
    // localIp);

    hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
    hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getAwsConfig().setEnabled(true);

    // hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().getInterfaces().setEnabled(true).addInterface(localIp);

    if (amazonConfig.containsKey("region")) {
        hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getAwsConfig().setRegion(amazonConfig.getString("region"));
    }
    if (amazonConfig.containsKey("accessKey")) {
        hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getAwsConfig()
                .setAccessKey(amazonConfig.getString("accessKey"));
    }
    if (amazonConfig.containsKey("secretKey")) {
        hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getAwsConfig()
                .setSecretKey(amazonConfig.getString("secretKey"));
    }

    try {
        String hazelcastGroup = System.getenv("HAZELCASTGROUP");

        logger.info("Join Hazelcast Nodes with Tag HAZELCASTGROUP and Value " + hazelcastGroup);

        hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getAwsConfig().setTagKey("HAZELCASTGROUP");
        hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getAwsConfig().setTagValue(hazelcastGroup);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Cannot detect hazelcastgroup: " + e.getMessage(), e);

        throw e;
    }

    mgr = new HazelcastClusterManager(hazelcastConfig);

    vertxOptions = new VertxOptions().setClusterManager(mgr).setClustered(true);
```

**Solution**

```
// privateIp = doHttpUrlConnectionAction("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4");

hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().setPublicAddress(privateIp);
```

Dont disable setPortAutoIncrement

for the 1st Docker Image, you should set the port to 5701 via

```
hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().setPort(5701);
```

on the second Docker Image - 5702 and so on

You don't need to link the Docker Container. Just make a portmapping for each image.

Create a Security Group for this ports, so that other nodes can access the ports.

Comment: Are you facing problem with them not forming a cluster or not able to connect from a client? Please post the config details n cluster log statements.

Comment: I figure out, that the AWS Discovery just save the IP Address and not the port of the Hazelcast nodes. This means, if you're running ONE MultiDocker image with multiple Vert.x on differen ports. It's not possible to detect each other. Currently, i try to start a new docker process with a hazelcast server in it. the verx nodes register agains this internally hazelcast server. and this hazelcast server is reachable for other external nodes. but currently, i've no answer if this works.

Comment: I believe its the Public IP address config is what you are missing. So please post the HZ config details here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my recommendations. If it doesn't solve the problem then please post the HZ log statements.

1. Uncomment the line which adds a property for localAddress. `hazelcastConfig.setProperty("hazelcast.local.localAddress", localIp);`
2. Disable tcp-ip configuration explicitly.
3. Remove the setting of Public address second time.

   ```
   hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().setPublicAddress(privateIp);
   hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().setPortAutoIncrement(false);

   if (amazonConfig.containsKey("hazelcastPort")) {
        logger.info("Use port " + amazonConfig.getString("hazelcastPort") + " for hazelcast");
        hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().setPort(Integer.valueOf(amazonConfig.getString("hazelcastPort")));
   }
   ```
4. If you can, try to make use of default ports itself. As you pointed out in the comments, there was an issue with HZ not supporting custom ports. Also AWSClient specification doesn't allow specifying custom ports, they tend to use the default ports 5701,5702,5703. Here is the enhancement request that I had created few months back. https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-aws/issues/3
5. Also make sure the docker containers are able to communicate with each other.

Comment: Your comment was an inspiration. The correct solution i entered in my post. Thanks

Comment: The Main Problem was hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().setPortAutoIncrement(false); After removing this, it works.